# I am trying to make a fare calculator on python this code part of the code does not run after the print section

Tags: python-3.x

```
    if countinue == "No" or "no" :
  print ("Your journey is then from ",inp,"to",ins)
  if ins in mix1 and inp in mix1:
    print("Your fare is : £4.00")
  elif ins in mix2 and inp in mix2:
    print("Your fare is : £3.00 ")
  elif ins in mix3 and inp in mix3:
    print("Your fare is : £2.00")
  elif ins in mix1 and inp in mix2 or ins in mix2 and inp in mix1:
    print("Your fare is : £3.50 ")
  elif ins in mix1 and inp in mix3 or ins in mix3 and inp in mix1 :
    print("Your fare is : £3.00") 
  elif ins in mix2 and inp in mix3 or ins in mix3 and inp in mix2:
    print("Your fare is : £2.35")
```

Comment: `if countinue == "No" or "no" :` does not work the way you expect it.  It will be **always** `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the full question each time.

```
if countinue == "No" or continue == "no"
```

If you're doing this just because of the capital letter, you can use the lower method instead.

```
if countinue.lower() == "no"
```

This changes the variable data to lowercase before analysing it.